# Compiler for Bash

Tags: bash, compiler-construction

I am taking a Compiler Design course in my undergraduate studies. As a part of the learning process, I'd have to develop the compiler for a language.

Can a compiler be written for Bash? 
Would it be more difficult than designing a compiler for a regular programming language, like C/C++ and thus outright inconceivable, at least for a newbie?

Comment: Practically any language can be compiled. The general techniques are the same for all languages. The compiler parses the code, and figures out what the program does, generates executable code that does it. There's not much difference between compiling a bash `for` loop and a C `for` loop.

Comment: Isn't the "how" part supposed to be what you lean in the class? Are you sure you get to pick the language?  It's possible the language would be prescribed for you.

Comment: Does anyone know what happened to my comment?

Comment: You really don't want to write a parser for bash, and you probably don't want to write a parser for a basic Posix shell (although it would be quite a bit easier). There are just too many weird details and corner cases. Personally, I'd start with something a little simpler; if you really want to do a common shell programming language, you could think about awk., which at least has a reasonably regular syntax although its lack of lexical scope means that you will end up with idiosyncratic (though simple) identifier handling.

Comment: @barmar: Well, I'd tend to say the main difference is whether it's interpreted or compiled; if something is "compiled" then you'll likely end up with assembled code, rather than the same thing you started with.

Comment: @l'L'l A language is compiled if you write a compiler for it. You can write C interpreters, and you can write bash compilers.

Comment: @Barmar: A compiler transforms source code (the language) into another language — which I'm not disagreeing about if that's what you mean. The point I was trying to make was that the result of compilation is not always "executable code", as you mentioned - that's really all.

Comment: @l'L'l Technically true, but the most common use is to create executable code. Note that this doesn't necessarily mean machine code, it could be byte code to be executed by another interpreter (this is how Java, PHP and Python are typically executed). For the purposes of answering the original question, it doesn't really matter how the target code will be executed (byte code is essentially machine code for a virtual machine).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can a compiler be written for Bash?

Yes.  (Existence proof - [`shc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shc_the_shell_script_compiler).)

> If yes, how?

That's the hard part.

POSIX shell languages are very different to typical programming languages because of the effects of things like backticks, variable substitution, quoting, and so on.

You could ignore this and implement a "bash like" language, either leaving out the difficult features, or treating them in a way that doesn't conform to POSIX behavior.

Then ... there is the problem of how to generate something that is executable.  Again, that is possible (see above), but if your aim is to be faster than a regular shell then you need to do things like emulating the behavior of common Linux commands in the compiled code.  That is a huge task.

---

I'm not saying this is a bad project, but you will need to do a lot of work, including:

- finding, reading and (fully) understanding the POSIX shell specs
- researching how to implement a parser that deals with POSIX idiosyncracies
- figuring out which linux commands need to be implemented directly, and
- figuring out how to deal with the ones that you don't; e.g. all the complexity of pipelines.

Comment: ccsh is a non free project that boasts compiling shell scripts into a binary.

Comment: Thanks, but only one example is necessary for an existence proof.

Comment: SHC is not really a BASH compiler. It only encodes and encrypts shell code and packs it together with a decoder in a binary. On execeution of that binary the shell code gets decrypted and passed to the shell via the -c option. So you still need the shell interpreter to execute a "compiled" script. Also, this has the downside that everyone can inspect the decrpyted shell code through ps and similar tools. Additionally, you're limited by _SC_ARG_MAX, so your scripts can't be very large.

Comment: This question is about whether it is **possible** to write a compiler for bash.  The answer is (in short) **Yes**.  I provided "shc" as an existence proof.  That is all.